# SearchView honeycomb

Tags: android, search, widget

How do I change the color of a search widget's text

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:textColor="@color/black"   <---- this does not work. 
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

I created my own view but it looked terrible, is there a way to override text color.

Or do you know where the source/GIT of this widget is. Google did not do it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(canvas.getContext());
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I don't think you can customize the text inside the searchView. You would have to set the color of the searchView itself.